# Как сделать, чтобы когда мы нажимали div1, то вызывалась function1, но также нажимался и div2, который бы сделал function2?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

У нас есть div1 и div2. div1 делает function1, а div2 - function2. У div1 onclick не работает(я серьёзно), а у div2 всё работает. Как сделать, чтобы когда мы нажимали div1, то вызывалась function1, но также нажимался и div2, который бы сделал function2? Кстати, мы никак не можем влиять на function1, изменять его и даже обращаться к нему=)

Comment: Нужно сделать так чтоб при нажатии на div1 вызывался function1

Answer (score 1):

`<div onclick="console.log(2)"><div onclick="console.log(1)">1</div></div>`

Comment: Согласен с этим вариантом, только у меня всегда вызывается именно div1(у вас: <div onclick="console.log(1)"></div>), независимо от того, какое будет z-index. Как сделать, чтобы вызывался не только div1, но и div2?

Comment: Так у меня клик баблится через оба дива.
Вы бы код в вопрос положили, как у вас там. что не работает? и зачем оно вообще?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="div1" onclick="alert('div1');">div 1</div>
<div id="div2" onclick="alert('div2');">div 2</div>

<div id="div3" onclick="alert('div1');alert('div2');">div 1 + 2</div>
```

Не работает?

Comment: Весь прикол в том, что мы не можем обратиться к function1,  то есть, как на вашем примере, к alert('div1');, поэтому не можем сказать <div id="div3" onclick="alert('div1');alert('div2');">div 1 + 2</div>

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял

```html
<div class="div1">1</div>
<div class="div2">2</div>
```

```js
const div1 = document.querySelector('.div1')
const div2 = document.querySelector('.div2')
div2.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(2))
div1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(1)
  div2.click()
})
```